# Как в проект eclipse загрузить изображение для фона?

Tags: изображения, android, eclipse

Как в проект eclipse загрузить изображение для фона?

Answer (score 2):

Можно руками в файловом менеджере перекинуть изображение в папку **.../res/drawable**.
Потом выделить папку проекта в эклипсе в менеджере пакетов/проектов и нажать F5 (обновить).
Можно еще через File->Import.

Answer (score -1):

`String img_path = "с:\\_temp\\images\\";`, а потом используешь `img_patch`.